# How to edit an item in a list: C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list

OK, so I have learned how to create a list, view items in the list, and use the items in the list. I now want to learn how to edit the information that is in the list.

Here is my list:

```
 class ObjectProperties
        {
            public string ObjectNumber { get; set; }
            public string ObjectComments { get; set; }
            public string ObjectAddress { get; set; }


        }

        List<ObjectProperties> Properties = new List<ObjectProperties>();
```

This is how I am adding values to the list:

```
 ObjectProperties record = new ObjectProperties
            {
                ObjectNumber = txtObjectNumber.Text,
                ObjectComments = txtComments.Text,
                ObjectAddress = addressCombined,
            };

            Properties.Add(record);
```

I am wanting the user to enter which number they want to update by using a textbox(txtUpdateObjectNumber). I then want to compare that number to the values that are stored in record.ObjectNumber and then if it exist I want to replace the information in record.ObjectNumber and record.ObjectComments where record.ObjectNumber == txtUpdateObjectNumber. If you need me to elaborate on anything just let me know. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: From what you've said it seems to me that you would be better off with a `Dictionary<String, ObjectProperties>()`...plus your "ObjectNumber" might be better represented by an int, or an uint.

Comment: But the object number has to be able to change.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the list item, use linq:

```
ObjectProperties opFound = Properties.Find(x => x.ObjectNumber == txtUpdateObjectNumber.Text);
```

Or the delegate form:

```
ObjectProperties opFound = Properties.Find(delegate (ObjectProperties x) { return x.ObjectNumber == txtUpdateObjectNumber.Text; });
```

Once you've found the item in the list, any changes you make to `opFound`, including the `ObjectNumber`, will persist in the list.

Comment: Do you know I would change the values in the list once I did that?

Comment: This will return the `ObjectProperties` object; any changes you make to that property will be persisted in the list.